# Cannot retrive data using dataset from database

Tags: c#, web-services

I am writing web service method to retrieve the data of the user. To make clear, I have a table called User in my database, which has, ID, fName, lName, emailAddress, username, password, reg_ID. If i used the ID to retrieve the data, it will work but instead if i use emailAddress in "where" clause, it gives me following error.

**Web service method**

```
 [WebMethod(Description = "Returns Details of User with username")]
        public DataSet GetUser(string user)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            try
            {
                oleConn.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [username]=" + user;
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oleConn);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "User");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                oleConn.Close();
            }
            if (dataSet.Tables["User"].Rows.Count <= 0)
                return null;

                return dataSet;
        }
```

**Error**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at UserManagement.UserRegistration.GetUser(String user) in C:\Users\smartamrit\Desktop\SystemSoftware\UserManagement\UserRegistration.asmx.cs:line 170
```

Line 170 starts at
 `if (dataSet.Tables["User"].Rows.Count <= 0`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use single quotes while passing the email id or try to use like statement when passing email id. Have you check whether any exception raises in the catch block.

The possible reason is there may occur a exception in catch block, it was suppressed and after that the if statement has executed and throwed a error that user table was not found.

Comment: i just passed it through browser, as when you develop web service method, it automatically creates field to enter

Comment: Yes, it happens whenever you pass a parameter in webservice.

Comment: but if i pass ID instead of username it works (after changing in the code int uID, Where[ID] = + uID)

Comment: Yes.. Because for Integer value, you dont need to enclose it with single quotes. But for string values, you have to enclose it with quotes.

Comment: And as @Droid said, Use parameterized query. Its a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If the query does not return any rows, no tables are added to the DataSet. Thus

```
dataSet.Tables["User"]
```

is probably null.

You need to check the return value of the Fill method to ensure that rows were returned.

Per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz.aspx) the fill method returns an integer which represents:

> The number of rows successfully added to or refreshed in the DataSet. This does not include rows affected by statements that do not return rows.

Furthermore, your query is open to sql injection (a security vulnerability). You will want to change it to use [parameterized queries](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries) instead.

Comment: but if i used ID which is primary key instead of username, it returns the data.

Comment: did you leave your query exactly as it appears here? if so your where clause says "Where [username]= USERS_EMAIL" which will of course yield 0 results, which in turn leads to your null reference exception on line 170. In anycase, even if you did get the result you want, whenever the query fails to return any results, your code will throw an exception. You need to check if there was at least 1 row returned before you can do run any methods on dataSet.Tables["YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE"]

Comment: but when i run webservice in browser, i m passing the user's username to retrieve the data. Why does it work when i pass ID, and why it doesnot work when i pass username

Comment: are you calling the same method when you pass id versus username? You said in your question you were passing email address. if your calling the same method, your query will not work for all of those different fields. try passing a made up ID (e.g. "abc1234555") and the same exception will be thrown because the query does not return any rows.

Comment: yes i am calling same method but changing the code to accept ID no the username.

Comment: Your SQL query is probably failing. When you pass ID your query is fine because numbers dont need qoutes. When you pass username (text) your query will fail. Your query needs to have ticks (qoutes) around the username. (E.g. SELECT * FROM User WHERE username= 'john')